# unable to use utility method to check if multiple edittext are empty with custom correct edittext id in output toast

Tags: java, android

Thanks for reading this
I am having difficulty  a utility method meant to read all 20 edittexts and check if they are empty and return custom toast messages for instances of each editText being empty
The utility method is called inside my onclicklistener as seen below. Its called checkEmpty

```
  btnRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (checkEmpty(etPickupLocation, getActivity())) return;

            }
        });
```

see checkempty below

```
  public static boolean checkEmpty(EditText myEditText, Context context) {
        String editTextIdInt= String.valueOf(myEditText.getId());
        Log.d(TAG, "checkEmpty: editTextIdInt>> "+ myEditText.getId());
        String editTextIdStr = context.getString(Integer.parseInt(editTextIdInt));
        Log.d(TAG, "checkEmpty: editTextIdStr >>"+ editTextIdStr);

        if (myEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, editTextIdStr+" is missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The issue is : I want to return the id of the editTextResource (etPickupLocation) as the second log output but instead i keep getting false

log output

```
2020-09-20 10:33:21.556 11445-11445/com.packagename.clasname D/UTILITYLOG: checkEmpty: editTextIdInt>> 2131230927
2020-09-20 10:33:21.556 11445-11445/com.packagename.clasname D/UTILITYLOG: checkEmpty: editTextIdStr >>false
```

All I want is to get the id of the editext bein passed into the method so i can return the right toast method
or is there a better approach to doing this?
Help me out guys

Comment: `View` IDs have no relation to string resource IDs. That is, you cannot use an `EditText`'s ID to retrieve a string resource. Beyond that, it's not quite clear what you mean to do, exactly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification Mike. I needed that. Ill use a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much to Mike Ms clarification
I decided to use this approach instead since I cannot use an EditText's ID to retrieve a string resource.

```
  public static boolean checkEmpty(EditText myEditText, Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkEmpty: Obj" + myEditText.toString());
        String myObj = myEditText.toString();
        String OutputText="";
        if (myObj.contains("etPickupLocation")) {
            OutputText = "Sender Address";
        }else if (myObj.contains("etWhereTo")) {
            OutputText = "Recipient Address";
  } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkEmpty: >> DOING NOTHING");
            OutputText = "Something";

        }

        if (myEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Enter "+OutputText+"." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```